# SQLAlchemy searchable: "Function tsq_parse does not exist" on full text search

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to enable full text search on a model's column using SQLAlchemy-searchable. I followed the instructions on their [quickstart guide](https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#quickstart) and applied the fix specified in [this github issue](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-searchable/issues/66) given that I'm using Flask. Also, I already created and applied the migrations as specified in [Alembic Migrations](https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alembic_migrations.html#alembic-migrations) docs section. However, the following exception is being raised:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function 
tsq_parse(unknown, unknown) does not exist

LINE 3: WHERE quote.qt_search_vector @@ tsq_parse('pg_catalog.englis...
                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
to add explicit type casts. [SQL: 'SELECT quote.id AS quote_id, quote.song_id AS
quote_song_id, quote.stanza_id AS quote_stanza_id, quote.popularity_count AS
quote_popularity_count, quote.quote_text AS quote_quote_text,
quote.qt_search_vector AS quote_qt_search_vector \nFROM quote \nWHERE
quote.qt_search_vector @@ tsq_parse(%(tsq_parse_1)s, %(tsq_parse_2)s) \n
LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: {'tsq_parse_1': 'pg_catalog.english',
'tsq_parse_2': '"ipsum"', 'param_1': 10}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Am I missing something?

**__init__.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_searchable import make_searchable

Base = declarative_base()
make_searchable(Base.metadata)

... more code ...
```

**Model**

```
class QuoteQuery(BaseQuery, SearchQueryMixin):
    pass


class Quote(db.Model):
    query_class = QuoteQuery
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('song_id', 'stanza_id', 'quote_text'),)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    song_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id'), nullable=False)
    stanza_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stanza.id'), nullable=True)
    popularity_count = db.Column(
        db.BigInteger, unique=False, nullable=False, server_default='1')
    quote_text = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False, nullable=False)
    qt_search_vector = db.Column(TSVectorType('quote_text'))
```

**Query**

```
term = 'lorem'
Quote.query.search('"' + term + '"').all()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here troubleshooting for a day on this.  Maybe this will help someone else.  I was also sometimes missing function `parse_websearch` instead of `tsq_parse` but I wasn't able to narrow down why it gave one or the other before I fixed it.

My issue was I upgraded sqlalchemy_searchable (from 0.10.2 to 1.4) and my database version (Postgres 9.6) was too old now.  I needed to manually create some functions now from sqlalchemy_searchable but I was missing a Postgres function (specifically `websearch_to_tsquery` that was added in 11).

I was using Flask-Migrate/Alembic for migrations.  I got help from [here](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-searchable/issues/67) and ended up making a blank migration (`flask db revision` to do that).  I pasted in the SQL from [here](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-searchable/blob/master/sqlalchemy_searchable/expressions.sql).  My new migration looked like this.

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'AAA'
down_revision = 'BBB'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

def upgrade():
    command = """
              CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_websearch(config regconfig, search_query text)
              RETURNS tsquery AS $$
              SELECT
                  string_agg(
                      (
                          CASE
                              WHEN position('''' IN words.word) > 0 THEN CONCAT(words.word, ':*')
                              ELSE words.word
                          END
                      ),
                      ' '
                  )::tsquery
              FROM (
                  SELECT trim(
                      regexp_split_to_table(
                          websearch_to_tsquery(config, lower(search_query))::text,
                          ' '
                      )
                  ) AS word
              ) AS words
              $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
              
              
              CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_websearch(search_query text)
              RETURNS tsquery AS $$
              SELECT parse_websearch('pg_catalog.simple', search_query);
              $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;"""

    op.execute(command)

def downgrade():
    op.execute('DROP FUNCTION public.parse_websearch(regconfig, text);')
    op.execute('DROP FUNCTION public.parse_websearch(text);')
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the metadata I was providing the make_searchable function. Fixed make_searchable call:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_searchable import make_searchable

db = SQLAlchemy()
make_searchable(db.metadata)
```

After this, I called db.create_all() and the full text search started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For those not using Flask, this was my solution:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers

db_engine = create_engine(...)
configure_mappers()

Base = declarative_base()
make_searchable(Base.metadata)
Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)
```

The missing piece was the `Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)`